# I am trying to get an image background behind a button and title. I am just learning how to use HTML, so very new without any previous experience

Tags: html

style=" background-image: url("https://mars.nasa.gov/system/resources/detail_files/26895_PIA25326-web.jpg");

I am trying to get this to be the background behind a button and title.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button 
 style='background-image: url("https://mars.nasa.gov/system/resources/detail_files/26895_PIA25326-web.jpg')
```

> hello

use single quote around background-image because you are using double quotes in URL to avoid conflict as html will consider the quotes at the beginning of background-image & beginning of URL as start and end of tag which will cause conflict and will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a containing element. Set the `background-image` of the containing element.

```css
.container {
  background-image: url(https://mars.nasa.gov/system/resources/detail_files/26895_PIA25326-web.jpg);
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```